# Typescript mysteriously won't lint in VSCode with a large ts file in Svelte

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, svelte, vite

I'm not even sure where to start with this.

I have a .ts file with a ton of classes, very intertwined with each other, as part of a pretty big Svelte application. Everything was going well until about yesterday. I noticed the linter was doing something funky, and then made my changes anyway and it seemed to adjust itself. The file itself is about 3000 lines. Today, the same thing happened but did not re-adjust itself. For some reason, the typescript linter just acts really funny. Here's what I've boiled it down to:

1. When the file is left as is and I am working on it, it seems as though there are no type errors (though I know for sure there is at least a couple), but syntax errors still show up. For example, I can change a type name to one that doesn't exist and no "problems" will show up, or even reference variables that don't exist and the VSCode won't scream at me. But if I put two dots next to each other I will instantly get a linting with a syntax error.
2. If I delete *some* classes or type definitions, suddenly type errors appear everywhere (as you would expect when you delete a class or type). I don't exactly know why which ones do it or not. Maybe it has to do with the sheer quantity or some interaction they have with something else I'm not aware of. When I put the piece of code back in, the errors remain as they were - as if the linter had crashed and left with the remnants of the previous errors. I can get the errors to go away by changing the language mode to something else and then back to TypeScript, but then I'm back at square one where I seem to be getting NO type errors at all even though I know there are some.
3. Only this file is affected, type errors work just fine in all other files.

It seems as though it's only the typing that gets affected. I still have the full coloring of variables and other syntactical stuff. It's just for some reason, the typing gets stuck or crashes. I don't know how to deal with this. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. The editor will disable code hints on some files that are sufficiently large. (I've only run into this using very large JSON files.) The solution would be to break your 3,000 line giga-file into a number of smaller files, at which point code hinting should work again.
2. The editor contains an option called `TypeScript › Tsserver: Max TS Server Memory` which is probably used for code completion. The default minimum is 3000MB though, which is already a lot.

Comment: Thanks! That's incredibly inconvenient because everything depends on everything in this file. Is there a setting somewhere I can change?

Comment: Yes (edited) but I cannot advise you to do so as it does not really fix your problem. If you don't break your file up into smaller files, you are unlikely to have success with this project regardless of editor.